# Iphone loading an URL to a variable - static works, dynamic from XML falls over

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I load my XML in to my iphone app via:

```
NSArray *Images = [doc nodesForXPath:kName_logo error:nil];//Root node
for (CXMLElement *ImgIcons in Images) 
{
    NSArray *locImage = [ImgIcons elementsForName:kName_image];
    for(CXMLElement *fullImage in locImage) 
    {
        LocationImage = fullImage.stringValue;
        locStatImage = LocationImage;
        NSLog(@"Image Found %@",LocationImage);
        break;
    }
}
```

Which is fine, it's bringing me back the correct string

```
2011-11-03 14:48:43.572 Del Search[13152:f203] Image Found http://de1128/directenquirieswebapplicationv3.0/images/logos/PremierInn.jpg
```

However, When I load it on to my table through the following:

```
if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierImage];

        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierImage] autorelease];
            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,180)];                
            imageView.tag = 1;
            NSURL *Imageurl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", locStatImage]];
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:Imageurl];
            UIImage *img = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];
            imageView.image = img;

            [cell addSubview:imageView];
            [imageView release];


        }
        return cell;
    }
```

The app falls over. However if I manually set locStatImage by doing:

```
locStatImage = @"http://de1128/directenquirieswebapplicationv3.0/images/logos/PremierInn.jpg";
```

It works fine. What' am I doing wrong when I set locStatImage?

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the two code snippets above are from separate methods, `locStatImage` is probably being autoreleased between you obtaining it from the XML and using it in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Further assuming `locStatImage` is a retained property (if it isn't it should be), in your first code sample you should use

```
self.locStatImage = ...
```